# Antlr 4 parser rules, why is output of 'grun' influenced by unrelated rules?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I define the following silly grammar, for testing purposes:

```
grammar Test;
x: ab 'b' ab EOF;
y: ab+ EOF;
ab: 'a' 'b'?;
```

I execute it as follows:

```
$  rm -f Test*.[^g]*; antlr Test.g && javac Test*.java \
   && echo -n "abab" | grun Test RULE -tree
```

For the three rules I get the following output:

```
RULE = x   -->    (x (ab a) b (ab a b) <EOF>)
RULE = y   -->    (y (ab a b) (ab a b) <EOF>)
RULE = ab  -->    (ab a b)
```

This looks like what I expected: rule `ab` doesn't consume the whole input, but tries to match as much of the beginning as it can.

Now I go to the grammar file and comment out rule `y`.  I repeat `grun` executions for the two remaining rules:

```
RULE = x   -->    (x (ab a) b (ab a b) <EOF>)
RULE = ab  -->    (ab a)
```

Output of `x` matching didn't change.  But output of `ab` did, though this rule didn't depend on `y` in any way.

Can anyone explain what's going on?  Is it some "undefined behavior", a bug or something I miss completely?  Tested on ANTLR 4.5.1.

**EDIT**: Opened [an issue](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/985), let's see what the official response is.